# Почему в Python не срабатывает конструкция if/else, написанная в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if

Знаю, что в python есть упрощенная конструкция if/else в одну строку: **(действие в случае выполнения условия) if (условие) else (действие в случае невыполнения условия)**. Но почему-то не могу заставить эту конструкцию работать:

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    l.pop(i) if l[i][0] in 'Мм' else pass
```

У меня есть список, элементы в котором являются словами (str).
Мне нужно просто удалить слова, начинающиеся на букву М, т.е. элемент из списка по индексу, сам элемент мне возвращать не требуется. Самое обидное, что в развёрнутом варианте инструкция отрабатывает корректно.

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i][0] in 'Мм':
        l.pop(i)
```

Пробовал вместо pass писать continue, пробовал ничего не писать, ругается на синтаксис и всё тут. Хочу понять, в чём мой промах?
P.S. Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой однострочный `if` называется тернарным оператором.

Используется он в основном, чтобы положить в переменную какое-то значение в зависимости от условий, но **не для вызова функции**, что пытаетесь сделать вы.

В принципе, с точки зрения синтаксиса так, как написали вы - писать можно (если заменить `pass` на `None`), но не нужно, потому что это примерно то же самое, что ложкой пытаться выкопать яму, логика в этом есть, но это странно, потому что `l.pop(i)` - это функция, которая изменяет объект, а не возвращает конкретный результат.

И обычно, когда вы делаете что-то явно не тем способом начинают возникать проблемы, как и в данном случае - это вызовет side effect, когда вы удалите первый элемент списка, то все последующие сдвинутся, и при индексации начнут пропускаться элементы и некоторые слова удовлетворяющие условию останутся в списке.

Если говорить в целом о вашей задаче:

> нужно удалить слова, начинающиеся на букву М

Можно сделать гораздо проще при помощи генератора списков, это тоже удобная однострочная конструкция:

```
l = [x for x in l if not x.startswith(('м', 'М'))]
```

Comment: Благодарю вас, очень дельный ответ! Про смещение элементов списка при его изменении  я упустил момент, согласен. Пойду знакомиться ближе с генераторами списков.

Comment: Возник ещё вопрос, не могу оживить такую конструкцию даже при попытке вложить в переменную значение: `ll = l[max_index:min_index] if max_index < min_index else ll = l[min_index:max_index]` В контексте этой темы хотелось бы узнать, почему выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса. P.S. Ваше решение с генератором списка оказалось очень изящным для решения предыдущей задачи, а моё решение действительно имело скрытые баги, которые открывались только при значительном кол-ве слов на букву "М" в строке.

Comment: @ДжонТраволтович `li =` в `else` - лишнее, на будущее - на сайте принято использовать один тикет для одного вопроса, если возник ещё один, то лучше создать новый

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо вам!